# Check string for valid input in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently working on an assignment where I need to validate some user input from a form(JSP and servlets). I use regex to check if i.e., phone number only contains integers. I want to do the same with name and surname, but I have some trouble understanding regex.

Allowed characters for "name" are letters, space and dash

My check for phonenumber which works:

```
else if(!number.matches("[0-9]+")){

                return false;
}
```

Allowed characters for "surname" are letters and dash ( not space )
So what I need help with is the expression for the names.

Comment: in the name, can space and dash be present the same time, if they are present. Or should only one occur at a time?

Answer (score 0):

For name you can use following regex :

```
[a-zA-Z -]+
```

And for username you can just remove the space from character class.

Start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/